# Vim - slimv : close-parenthesis position upon pressing enter

Tags: vim, common-lisp, slimv

I'm a vim user trying to learn common lisp. I run gvim on windows. I am trying to follow the slimv tutorial given here: http://kovisoft.bitbucket.org/tutorial.html

My question:suppose you type the following and press enter after `:morse` (the vertical bar denotes the cursor position)

```
(defpackage :morse|)
```

I get the following result (again the vertical bar '|' denotes the cursor position):

```
(defpackage :morse
  |
    )
```

Whereas I *want* the following result:

```
(defpackage :morse
  |)
```

so that I can continue to type to get the following:

```
(defpackage :morse
  (:use :common-lisp))
```

What should I do to get the result I want?

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it - the answer apparently lies in `:help g:paredit_electric_return`. I.e., insert the following in your _vimrc file:

```
let g:paredit_electric_return=1
```

Also see this feature in action:

[image]

Comment: Slimv author here. I'm glad you found out that this was the `g:paredit_electric_return` option. I'm going to mention this also in the tutorial, thanks for drawing my attention to that. *Note*: you need to set the option to 0 if you want to disable electric returns.